# Packet and Byte counter

Tags: iptables

How I increase the number of Packet counter and Byte counter in FORWARD DROP [0:0] in iptables rules? Why it shows '0'?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the counters for the default rule (policy) of the `FORWARD` chain, which contains rules applied to packets being forwarded  *through* the host. That only applies to routers, not your usual hosts with only one network interface, which would only see use on `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains. Also, forwarding/routing has to be explicitly enabled via a sysctl, for IPv4 the knob is `net.ipv4.ip_forward`.